# Problem parsing dependency on any apt command

Tags: debian, command-line, asus

When i try to run any apt, apt-get or anything like, i get errors such as:

```
E: Problem parsing dependency 20
E: Error occurred while processing acqi-s5pport (NewVersion2)
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/http.debian.net_debian_dists_stretch_main_binary-armhf_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

After some google, i was recommended to backup dpkg and replace it with the old version. This has not solved my problem.

I have tried to `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` but still no luck.

The box is the Asus Tinkerboard, running their Linaro build, debian based i belive.

Comment: Did you try `apt-get clean`?

Comment: Tried now, didnt help - no output

Comment: apt-get dist-upgrade?

Comment: Try removing `/var/lib/apt/lists/http.debian.net_debian_dists_stretch_main_binary-armhf_Packages` before running `apt-get update`.